# Why am I getting "command not found" error on my VS?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, python3

```
/bin/sh: python3.11.1: command not found

[Done] exited with code=127 in 0.003 seconds
```

I am using VS for macOS.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't installed Python, or VS is not correctly set configured.

First, Python and VS Code need to be correctly installed.

Second, you need to install the
[Python extension for VS Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python)
from the Visual Studio Marketplace.

Third, for Python3, VS Code needs additional configuration in
the `tasks.json` file.

To get to that file, in VS Code (mac) enter
<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>,
type `task` and select "configure task runner".
Edit the file to point "command" at "python3" and the
(command line) arguments to point at `${file}`, then Save.

The `tasks.json` file should look like this :

[image]

References :

- [Getting Started with Python in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial)
- [How to Use Python3 in Visual Studio Code](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1094003/How-to-Use-Python-in-Visual-Studio-Code)

Comment: There is no such line as  "Configure task runner". The two options to select from are 'Configure Default Build Task' and 'Configure Task'.

Comment: I don't have VS Code here, and the advice above is from 2016. Things have changed, so you will need to check the task definition in your setup. If you find anything, let me know and I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

There might be several reasons /bin/sh not to find your python binary.

You should revisit [VSCode manual](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments) on adding python environment variables to your VSCode, specifically you should re-select your interpreter as shown in above link.

Next thing is to check (outside of VSCode) if your default interpreter is really a /bin/sh and you can run that command from there.

- open a command line and type:

  `echo $SHELL`
- if it differs from /bin/sh you should also change it in VSCode (as show for example [here](https://medium.com/fbdevclagos/updating-visual-studio-code-default-terminal-shell-from-bash-to-zsh-711c40d6f8dc))